# how to pass content to jekyll default converter after custom conversion?

Tags: ruby, markdown, jekyll, kramdown

I am trying to write a jekyll plugin which do something on markdown files first and passing the content back to the default converter

For example,

```
module Jekyll
    class RMarkdownConverter < Converter
        safe :false
        priority :high

        def matches(ext)
            ext =~ /^\.(md|markdown)$/i
        end

        def output_ext(ext)
            ".html"
        end

        def convert(content)
            # do something with content
            # then pass it back to default converter
        end
    end
end
```

Right now, the closest thing that I could get it

```
converter = Jekyll::Converters::Markdown::KramdownParser.new(@config)
converter.convert(content)
```

But all the highlighting codes are losing color...and I suspect there are other problems...

My question is:
what is a correct way to invoke the default converter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how to do it:

```ruby
module Jekyll
    class MyConverter < Converter
        safe :false
        priority :high

        def matches(ext)
            ext =~ /^\.(md|markdown)$/i
        end

        def output_ext(ext)
            ".html"
        end

        def convert(content)
            # do your own thing with the content
            content = my_own_thing(content)

            # Now call the standard Markdown converter
            site = Jekyll::Site.new(@config)
            mkconverter = site.getConverterImpl(Jekyll::Converters::Markdown)
            mkconverter.convert(content)
        end
    end
end
```

Basically, you were right in using `Jekyll::Converters::Markdown`, but you need not specify `KramdownParser`, as your chosen parser will be automatically chosen from `Jekyll::Site` when you pass `@config` into the constructor.

Comment: it turns out https://github.com/navarroj/krampygs solved my problem. Thanks for the input though.