# Simple Jekyll converter plugin not working

Tags: ruby, plugins, converters, jekyll

I'm trying to create a simple Jekyll Converter Plugin which is almost a complete clone of the [Converter Plugin in the Jekyll Documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#converters), but it doesn't seem to work:

```
module Jekyll
  class MyConverter < Converter
    safe false
    priority :high

    def matches(ext)
      ext =~ /^\.(md|markdown)$/i
    end

    def output_ext(ext)
      ".html"
    end

    def convert(content)
      content.upcase
    end
  end
end
```

I've placed this file `my_converter.rb` into my `_plugins` directory.

Now when I do `bundle exec jekyll serve`, I expect to see the content of every markdown page that is rendered to HTML converted to uppercase. However, nothing seems to happen.

What am I missing? (I'm a Ruby novice, btw.)

Comment: PS, I've tried the suggestion in this SO answer (feeding my preprocessed `content` String into the default Markdown converter), to no avail. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761691/how-to-pass-content-to-jekyll-default-converter-after-custom-conversion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem solved. It turns out that there's nothing wrong with the above code.

The problem was that at some point, the github-pages gem had been added to our Gemfile (unneeded). Apparently, with the github-pages plugin, [Jekyll is always started in safe mode and the `plugin_dir` is a random string](https://github.com/github/pages-gem/blob/bd1018072aab370ddf63aa9c3938867e2133ac80/lib/github-pages/configuration.rb#L45-L70).

Removing the github-pages gem from our Gemfile fixed it!